# How do drivers automatically install?

Tags: windows, drivers

When I get a new peripheral, like a fancy mouse, or a new keyboard, normally I see that a driver is installing.

Once the driver for the device has completely installed - the hardware works.

I'm curious (from a technical standpoint) how does windows detect a new device?

How does it have permission to automatically install onto a machine?

What code is written that pushes the driver software automatically?

Is this a Risk? Can this automatic software info be exploited?

Comment: Plug'n'Play - For information on MS' implementation see this MS article: [How Plug and Play Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781092(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am by no stretch going to claim to be an expert but I can give you a rough answer to your question and points. I am going to assume we are talking about Plug'n'Play devices such as USB peripherals.

Since you mention Windows I will explain how this works (AFAIK) first:

1. You plug the device in
2. The computer uses a standardised protocol to communicate with the device to acquire the devices Vendor ID (VID) and Product ID (PID).
3. Windows looks locally to see if it has the driver for that specific VID/PID already installed, if so hey presto Windows initialises the drivers for that device and the device works as if by magic.
4. If it can't find it installed, Windows then searches some pre-defined local directories that it knows may contain the drivers required for this device. Often when you install associated software, it will make these drivers available for the operating system. If it finds the driver then great, windows will go ahead and install it then initialise it for use with the connected device.
5. If it doesn't have the driver available locally then Windows will reach out to Windows Update and ask if it has the driver for the device you connected. Most big brands will have their drivers available through Windows Update and I can only hope there is some form of verification process or at least reputability checks of those with the ability to add to Windows Update to ensure malicious drivers do not get sent to your machine.
6. If all the above has failed well, unfortunately it seems you will have to manually source and install the drivers yourself.

This is probably an over simplified explanation of how it works but I feel this is sufficient to answer your question.

Some additional points to consider that also answer some of your more specific queries are:

- A lot of common devices (keyboard, mice, webcams, etc.) will use what's known as a Generic Driver. This driver is installed on the machine and can be used by any device that conforms to the defined features of the generic device. often 'fancy devices' will work on a generic driver until you install the full driver allowing limited functionality - for example a graphics tablet might install as a generic HID (human interface device) and perform like a mouse but without official drivers cannot distinguish between a finger and the pen and cannot detect things like pressure or angle.
- In terms of permissions, the service that installs the drivers is running as the SYSTEM user which has elevated privileges to make changes to your system. A device does not have permission to push code and execute it on your computer however some devices that do need specific software (like a 3G dongle) may have a generic mass storage device that contains the drivers that can appear and prompt you the user to instal the required software/drivers.

If anyone with more technical knowledge who can see anything that I have said is wrong or misleading then please comment or edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Many of these drivers are included in the base Windows install, others are hosted on Microsoft Update and so are already a "trusted source" for the OS.

Hardware contains unique identifiers which the OS uses to determine what the device is and which driver it requires. Once Windows has matched a unique identifier for a present piece of hardware to a driver, it can then choose the appropriate source, either a pre-existing driver, Windows Update, or it asks you for another source.

Obviously, the process is actually much more complicated than this, but this is a simplified version of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8, at least, has a `Device Install Service` which, to quote the service description:

> Enables a computer to recognize and adapt to hardware changes with little or no user input. Stopping or disabling this service will result in system instability.

This is a triggered service that starts whenever a new device is inserted and almost certainly is what installs the necessary device drivers for things like your memory stick.

The device drivers that it is able to install will only be drivers that are stored and handled by Microsoft.  It will not be downloading drivers from product manufacturers at all, but will (for security reasons) be limited to downloading from a specific group of Microsoft servers.

The hardware manufacturer will, for devices that require special drivers, submit their drivers to Microsoft in order to get them digitally signed in order for Windows to allow them to be loaded.  I would assume that part of this service would include the ability to have a driver be automatically be set to downloaded to computers.

Because the driver is already digitally signed, and because there is a system service ready to install device drivers Microsoft has a secure path through which they can guarantee that only "known good" software can get put on a machine.  Because Microsoft can verify the software is good they can leave out the requirement for UAC and simply install the software themselves.

As to whether it is secure.  It is as secure as you computer is.  Any method that could exploit the service to install their own software already has very deep and critical control of your computer and could almost certainly install more software without needing to exploit the Windows Device install service.  The other option is that whatever malware has control of several critical internet devices and has exposed the private keys that only Microsoft themselves has access to.

So, yes it should be secure.